# Sending a specific email from Woocommerce based on the product

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

Is it possible in Woocommerce to send a custom email to the customer instead of the regular welcome email when they buy a specific product?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this and add some custom text to the new order email that is sent to a customer.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_email_order', 'add_product_welcome_email_text', 10, 2 );

function add_product_welcome_email_text( $order, $sent_to_admin ) {

    if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) {

        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            $product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );

            // Use the name or product ID here
            if( $product->get_id() == 123 ) {
                echo 'My custom welcome email text.  Thanks for buying ' . $product->get_name();
            }
        }
    }
}
```